# Load the content of a div with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

With jQuery ajax I can load in a div a div of another page. My question is: can I load the content of a div, but not the div itself?. In this case, can I load "Some text" and #intern but not #extern ?

One solution is to load one on one each element inside #extern. But this is a simplified case and in the real case, there are a lot of things and makes this option not very convenient.

JQUERY AJAX:

```
$("#target").load("extern.html #extern");
```

INDEX.html:

```
<div id="target"></div>
```

EXTERN.html:

```
<div id="extern">
  Some text
  <div id="intern"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You were right about `$.children()` and `$.contents()` not working. I am going to delete my incorrect answer. I tested it out further on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ivan_sim/Lpdywkos/) (using its `echo` service), and managed to get part of it to work. Un-enclosed text like 'Some text' doesn't work too well with selectors.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jQuery.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) in combination with [.replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) to achieve the desired result:

```
$.get("extern.html").done(function(data) {
  $("#target").replaceWith(data);
});
```

Comment: Interesting option. This avoids the duplication of divs but has the limitation that I have to load everything in the extern

Answer (score 0):

After trying a lot of things I could find the answer:

```
$("#target").load("3-extern.html #extern" // I load the div and the content first
,function(){ $("#intern").unwrap(); } // I eliminate the loaded div that I do not need anymore
);
```